# Integrating R with Bloomberg

Tags: r, bloomberg

In the past, I have used the package RBloomberg to directly pull bloomberg data into R. I've also seen it go by the names Rbbg or R[Name Redacted]. It seems to me, however, that this package no longer exists. Is it still out there somewhere? If not, is there a package that achieves the same purpose?

Answer (score 3):

Are you aware of the [findata.org site](http://findata.org/r-name-redacted/) and its directory?

The code is also in a bazaar repository as well as GitHub repo.

Comment: the help file within R could see a little improvement though, extract the pdf file from the website, it's much clearer.

Comment: I am sure the authors will accept a patch to the documentation too.

Comment: When I try to install this using
`install.packages("RBloomberg",repos="http://r.findata.org/")`
I get 2 warnings of downloaded length != reported length and an error of malformed line. Same thing for
`install.packages("Rbbg",repos="http://r.findata.org/")` -- any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

This has been resurrected as Rblpapi.

https://github.com/Rblp/Rblpapi